# Archiving Azure Search Service

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Need suggestion on archiving unused data from search service and reload it back when needed(reload to be done later).

Initial design draft looks like this:

1. Find the keys from search service based on some conditions(like take inactive, how old) that need to be archived.
2. Run achiever job(need suggestion here, could be a web job, function app)
3. Fetch the data and insert to blob storage and delete it from the search service.

Now the real way is to run the job in the pool and should be asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

There's no right / wrong answer for this question. What you need to do is perform batch queries (up to 1000 docs), and schedule it to archive past data (eg. run an Azure function which will trigger and search for docs where createdDate > DataTime.Now).

Then persist that data somewhere (can be a cosmos db or as blob into storage account). Once you need to upload it again, I would consider it as a new insert, so it should follow your current insert process.

You can also take a look on this tool which helps to copy data from your index pretty quick:

https://github.com/liamca/azure-search-backup-restore